# How to pass argument to route?

Tags: flutter

I try to pass argument "_difficulty" from "First page" to "Second page" but i don't understand how to do this:
This argument is a String and represent difficulty mode (easy, normal, hard)

**First page:** 
When user click on button, OnPressed is called

```
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/gamepage', arguments: _difficulty);
},
```

**Second page**
This call receive argument to show value

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class GamePage extends StatelessWidget {    
  final String difficultyMode;
  GamePage(this.difficultyMode);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final GamePage args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      body:  new Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Text(args.difficultyMode)
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**In main.dart:**
I using onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,

```
Route _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name){
      case '/':
        return _buildRoute(settings, new Homepage());
      case '/credits':
        return _buildRoute(settings, new Credits());
      case '/gamepage':
        return _buildRoute(settings, new GamePage(diffculty));
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get your arguments with the `RouteSettings`.

You can access it like:

```
case '/gamepage':
    String difficulty = settings.arguments;
    return _buildRoute(settings, new GamePage(difficulty));
```

Hope that helps!